# Convert RecyclerView items to CardView on click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I want to change my RecyclerView items to a CardView with a few buttons(that I'll do by myself). I don't understand how to convert it to a cardview on click.

Here's my code: 
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RVAdapter rvAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    rvAdapter = new RVAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
}

private List<RVData> getData() {
    List<RVData> data = new ArrayList<>();
    String [] titles = {"Dummy Text1", "Dummy Text2", "Dummy Text3"};
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
        RVData current = new RVData();
        current.title = titles[i];
        data.add(current);
    }
    return data;
}
```

RVAdapter.java

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.RVAdapterHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<RVData> data;
Context context;

public RVAdapter(Context context, List<RVData> mData) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    data = mData;
}

@Override
public RVAdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_row, parent, false);
    RVAdapterHolder rvAdapterHolder = new RVAdapterHolder(view);
    return rvAdapterHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RVAdapterHolder holder, int position) {
    RVData rvData = data.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(rvData.title);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public class RVAdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    public RVAdapterHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
}
}
```

RVData.java

```
public class RVData {
    public String title;
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"   
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

rv_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/dummy_title" />
</LinearLayout>
```

rv_card_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardElevation="2.5dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why you want to do that with recyclerview.? It is not best practice

Comment: See I don't want to actually convert it but when the user clicks on an item of the list it  should become a card which I can obtain from cardview only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place both the layouts into a single one and then simply change the visibility of the card when clicked. Try something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardElevation="2.5dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" /> <!-- this -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/dummy_title" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how do I go about actually implementing that in the code with RecyclerView and how will I make sure that it is in the same position as the RecyclerView. Also, to change the visibility will make all of the elements of RecyclerView go and just one card to appear. I want only one item at a time. How to do it for specific item is the real challange.

Comment: use this as your `rv_row.xml` inflated in `RecyclerView`. In your onClick  method call `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` on the card.